# Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js), Compound selectors may no longer be extended

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, webpack, sass

I am getting this error when I try to run **"npm start"** or **"ng serve"**. I am using **node version v11.15.0**, npm version **6.7.0**.

```
ERROR in ./src/app/shared/components/pop-up/pop-up.component.scss
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js):
                    @extend button.mat-button.default-button;
                           ^
      Compound selectors may no longer be extended.
Consider `@extend button, .mat-button, .default-button` instead.
    ╷
116 │                     @extend button.mat-button.default-button;
    │                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    ╵
  stdin 116:29  root stylesheet
      in xyz/src/app/shared/components/pop-up/pop-up.component.scss (line 116, column 29)
ERROR in ./src/app/core/authentication/login/login.component.scss
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js):
            @extend button.mat-button.default-button;
                   ^
      Compound selectors may no longer be extended.
Consider `@extend button, .mat-button, .default-button` instead.
   ╷
59 │             @extend button.mat-button.default-button;
   │                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ╵
  stdin 59:21  root stylesheet
      in xyz/src/app/core/authentication/login/login.component.scss (line 59, column 21)
ERROR in ./src/app/modules/abc/components/scan-input/scan-input.component.scss
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js):
:host /deep/ .mat-radio-label {
     ^
      Expected selector.
   ╷
43 │ :host /deep/ .mat-radio-label{
   │       ^
   ╵
  stdin 43:7  root stylesheet
      in xyz/src/app/modules/abc/components/scan-input/scan-input.component.scss (line 43, column 7)
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.
```

**I also tried few solutions like -**

```
npm rebuild node-sass
npm install --save-dev  --unsafe-perm node-sass
npm install node-sass
```

but unfortunately none of them worked in my favor. I need help in resolving this issue.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: @DiogoMagro I have answered the solution in the answers section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I myself tried one solution, and it's working perfectly. The way of handling the above styling has changed. So, Instead of

```
@extend button.mat-button.default-button;
```

It will be written as

```
@extend button, .mat-button, .default-button;
```

This solution worked.